# How to print all lines of a file except i.e commented with("#") In python

Tags: python, list, file

How to print all lines of a file except i.e commented with("#") in python?

Sample data:

```
World is suffering from the penidemic due to corona. 
#Stay safe #stay home
focus on boosting immunity#stay fit
Pray for all the corona warriors.
```

My attempt:

```
with open('file.txt','r') as f:
    b=[line.strip().split() for line in f if not line.startswith(('#'))]
```

The output for code contains 'immunity#safe'

I want to ignore the commented text.
I don't know how to proceed further.please help, thanks

Comment: Your code only looks at whether a line *starts with* a `#`, but it also looks like if a line contains a `#` partway through, you want to eliminate everything past that point -- right?

Comment: ...so, as some starting points for you to use yourself: You could use `split('#')` to split a line into pieces, and then take only the first piece (so, `split('#')[0]`). Or you could use a regex, with `re.sub()` or similar.

Comment: BTW, why are you using `strip()` with no arguments? Is it really the right thing to remove leading and trailing whitespace? (I don't see anything in your stated requirements that calls for doing that).

Comment: ...similarly, I'm not sure why `split()` is the right thing either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `str.split()` with `maxsplit=1` parameter.

For example:

```
data = []
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f_in:
    for line in f_in:
        line = line.split('#', maxsplit=1)[0].strip()
        if line:
            data.append(line)

print(data)
```

Prints:

```
['World is suffering from the penidemic due to corona.', 'focus on boosting immunity', 'Pray for all the corona warriors.']
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try using a regex like #.*
This will match everything but a newline after a # character.

Answer (score 0):

I would use Regex for this, the expression `r"(#.*?)\n"` selects the comments, and works correctly on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com) `Python Flavor, Regex v43`, but I'm not sure how it translates to Python, so it's not of much use sadly. It works by grouping everything from the character `#` to a newline